# CarrierWave image without bitly url

Tags: ruby, image, carrierwave

I'm working with a RubyOnRail application in AWS and the gem Carrierwave to upload images. The images upload normally, i haven't configure a bucket, the images are stored in the app

> irb(main):014:0> p.image.path
>   => "/var/app/current/public/uploads/pregunta/image/11/logo.png"

but when I echo the url of the image, return me a bitly url

> irb(main):013:0* p.image.url
>   => "http://ift.tt/1SAV3ZN/uploads/pregunta/image/11/logo.png"

Obviously, the link is broken. I just want to print a link like this one

> http://example.com/uploads/pregunta/image/11/logo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign the host name in a carrierwave config file like so (the asset_host field)

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_directory  = 'aws-bucket-name'
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.asset_host = 'http://www.example.com'
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}
end
```